# Setup cloudbees app to always have instances in different Regions

Tags: high-availability, cloudbees, regions

In the past month I've seen my cloudbees app being down due to cloudbees issues with its providers. Yesterday AWS East had problems and last summer this happened: http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/07/cloudbees-postmortem-on-two-recent.html

In order to achieve higher availability, I am wondering if would be a viable solution, and supported by cloudbees, to have always two instances open on different regions. Best would be if one of them could be EU.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that a Cloud application to be Highly Available must be multi-region on AWS. This has some serious impact on app architecture, with master/backup, data replication and such issues to address.

We (cloudbees) don't provide an out-of-the-box solution to this complex issue, that really depends on your requirements, data weight and update frequency, etc

Deployin in EU region is only available on Cloudbees for "dedicated servers" (contact sales@cloudbees.com for details and princing) but could be an option to get such a multi-region HA application